# laravel 5.1 + phpdesktop gives fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, phpdesktop

I am trying to use Laravel 5.1 with phpdesktop (https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop). I configured everything according to instructions but I get a fatal error for the first page itself.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding() in H:\app\laravel\www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration.php on line 43
```

I am unable to solve this problem. Both PHPDesktop and laravel versions are latest ones.
[image: Error when laravel 5.1 is used with phpdesktop]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `mbstring` extension for PHP.

Check [Enable mbstring extension on Windows](https://www.drupal.org/node/496948)